# core-plot zooming, axis x and y

Tags: ios, core-plot

How to make sure that the user could reduce the schedule until it is fully displayed?
And how to make zooming 3x max?
How to make that the user can not move the plot if `allowsUserInteraction` `= YES`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotSpace.globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(30)];
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1)length:CPTDecimalFromInt(25)];
    plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(70)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)length:CPTDecimalFromInt(70)];`

Now it work fine)